# rxswift: how to get the Observable<Any> resulting in a combination of Observable<[Category]>?

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift, reactivex, reactive

I have some doubts in my approach. I have two type of Observables:

```
//I can fetch from the server the houses and save them in the database
func houses() -> Observable<[House]>

//Given a houseId, I can fetch it's details and save them in the database
func houseDetail(id: Int) -> Observable<Family>
```

I would like to do an Observable which first fetch all houses, and then fetch the families. What I did is something like that:

```
//I am an observable which, when I complete, all data are saved
func fetchAllHousesAndFamily() -> Observable<Any> {
  var allHousesObservables: [Observable] = []
  for house in houses {
    allHousesObservables.append(houseDetail(house.id))
  }
  return Observable.combineLatest(allHousesObservables)
}
```

But this for...it doesn't seem to be *reactive style* to me, and it seems like a hack because I don't know enough about rx operators.

Do you have the right way to do it in the rxworld ?

Thank you

Comment: I think that your task has a more elegant solution. Can you share example code with your task on a Github? I want to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get all family from the result of `houses`, you will want to use the `flatMap` operator. `flatMap` accepts a closure with signature `T -> Observable<U>`, so, in our specific example, it will be a function of type `[House] -> Observable<Family>`.

```
houses().flatMap { houses in
  let details: [Observable<Family>] = houses.map { houseDetail($0.id) } // [1]

  return Observable.from(details).merge() // [2]
}
```

- [1]: We are mapping an array of house to an array of `Observable<Family>`.
- [2]: [`from(_:)`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/3c55a309a24fbe3dbc480431798eec072b633b85/RxSwift/Observables/Observable%2BCreation.swift#L189) converts `[Observable<Family>]` to `Observable<Observable<Family>>`. [`merge()`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/3c55a309a24fbe3dbc480431798eec072b633b85/RxSwift/Observables/Observable%2BMultiple.swift#L145) then transform it to `Observable<Family>`

We now have an observable that will emit one next event for each house with its family details.

If we'd prefer to keep the `House` value around, we could simply map again on the first line, like so:

```
let details: [Observable<(House, Family)>] = house.map { house in 
  houseDetail(house.id).map { (house, $0) }
}
```